# MovableRowsBetweenTables Feature working on desktop, but failing in mobile browser in Tabulator

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am using below code to move the rows between 2 tabulator tables with custom movableRowsReceiver event. as ex: https://tabulator.info/examples/5.5#movable-between-tables.

it is working as expected in the desktop, but on mobile it is not working. I get below error

[image]

to support my case, this is reproducible by the very sample provided by opening the page on mobile browser or by using device simulator.

[image]

example error screenshot